# What are the *actual* steps in ruby's method lookup?

Tags: ruby, object-model

I've read stackoverflow posts on this topic as well as several articles which include [A Primer on Ruby Method Lookup](https://gist.github.com/damien-roche/351bf4e7991449714533), [What is the method lookup path in Ruby](http://pascalbetz.github.io/ruby/2016/03/14/lookup-path/). In addition, I checked out the object model chapter in *Ruby Metaprogramming 2*, asked in a few chat rooms, and made [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/8i4gb4/question_about_module_singletons_and_the_object/). Short of learning C, I've done what I can to figure this out.

As described by the resources above, these 6 places are checked (in order) during method lookup on a receiving object like [fido_instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFR2E.png):

1. singleton class of fido_instance
2. IClass (from an extended module)
3. IClass (from a prepended module)
4. class
5. IClass (from an included module)
6. superclass (if method isn't found here, repeat steps 4-6)

Obviously, the diagram is incomplete, and all of these singleton classes might not have been created in the real world. Still, those 6 steps leave a lot to be desired, and don't cover the following scenario. If there were no extended/prepended IClass above the singleton class of `fido_instance`, then there's no explanation of whether step 4 is executed on the singleton class of `fido_instance`. I have to assume not since the whole method lookup would short circuit.

If I were to guess a set of steps that could explain ruby's method lookup behavior, it might look like:

1. check `fido_instance.class` for the method. (obviously, ruby isn't going to use its own #class method to do the method lookup, but it conveys the logic of the process)
2. check `fido_instance.class.superclass` for the method. Keep adding `.superclass` and checking for the method until no superclasses are left. (again, ruby isn't going to use its own #superclass method)
3. method wasn't found. Start at step 1, looking for #method_missing this time.

I also recall reading that there's a separate method lookup process if the receiving object is a class, but I can't recall where.

So what's the correct, detailed explanation that doesn't involve knowing C?

Comment: from an instance standpoint it would essentially be singleton_method -> prepended module method -> instance method -> included module method -> superclass instance method (recursively to Basic Object)

Answer (score 2):

There's a ... gem ... in that second ref that I think gets to the core of the answer: ancestors of the singleton class. Applied to your object, it would be:

`fido_instance.singleton_class.ancestors`

This will always give you the order of method lookup that Ruby uses. It's pretty simple when you view it this way, and that's the bottom line answer to your question. Ruby will start at the singleton_class and work its way up the ancestors looking for that method. Using your diagram:

```
fido.singleton_class.ancestors
=> [Fetch, WagTail, DogClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

(Note1: `Bark` is not part of this output because you used `extend` instead of `include`. More on this in a second.)

(Note2: If it doesn't find it all the way up to `BasicObject`, then it will call `method_missing` up the same ancestry chain.)

It's no different when calling a method on a class, because in Ruby a class it just an instance of class `Class`. So `DogClass.method1` will search for `method1` on `DogClass.singleton_class` and then up its ancestry chain, just like before.

```
DogClass.singleton_class.ancestors
=> [Bark, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Since you used `extend` for `Bark`, this is where we find it! So if `Bark` defined a method `bark`, then you can call `DogClass.bark` because that method is defined in `DogClass`'s singleton_class' ancestors.

To understand what that ancestry tree will be (instead of relying on printing it out every time), you simply need to know how the ancestry is modified by subclassing, `extend`, `include`, `prepend`, etc.

1. Subclassing gives the child class the entire ancestry chain of its superclass.
2. `include`ing a module in a class `C` adds that module into the ancestry chain after `C` and before everything else.
3. `prepend`ing a module in a class `C` adds that module into the ancestry chain before everything, including `C` and any currently prepended modules.
4. `def x.method1` adds `method1` to `x.singleton_class`. Similarly `x.extend(M)` will add `M` to the ancestry of `x.singleton_class` (but not to `x.class`). Note that the latter is exactly what happened with `Bark` and `DogClass.singleton_class`, but can equally apply to any object.

Leaving out `extend` from the above list because it does not modify the object's ancestry chain. It does modify the ancestry of that object's `singleton_class` -- as we saw, `Bark` was included in `DogClass.singleton_class.ancestors`.

---

Tangent:

The bit about class methods above is the key to me for understanding how important singleton classes are to Ruby. You obviously can't define `bark` on `DogClass.class`, because `DogClass.class == Class` and we don't want `bark` on `Class`! So how can we allow `DogClass` to be an instance of `Class`, allowing it to have a (class) method `bark` that is defined for `DogClass` but not unrelated classes? Using the singleton class! In this way, defining a "class method", like by `def self.x` inside class `C`, is sort of like `C.singleton_class.send(:define_method, :x) {...}`.